# Hibernate - Using java.time.Instant with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I get a `SchemaManagementException` because of a type mismatch. The Hibernate version is 5.2.8.Final. The `hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `validate`

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [end_date] in table [certificate]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
```

The column entity is of type `java.time.Instant`, and the PostgreSQL column is of type `TIMESTAMPTZ`.

```
@Column(name = "end_date")
private Instant endDate;
```

For `java.time.Instant`, the Hibernate type is `InstantType` which maps to a `TIMESTAMP` JDBC type. So I understand why the error says that it's expecting a `Types#TIMESTAMP`. What I don't understand is that the error says that it found a `Types#DATE`.

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

One workaround is to set the column definition as

```
@Column(name = "end_date", columnDefinition="DATE")
private Instant endDate;
```

but I am not really convinced it's a solution. To me an Instant is a `TIMESTAMP`, not a `DATE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is not the solution. For `java.time.Instant`, the PostgreSQL column should be of type `TIMESTAMP`. It was a mistake in the DB creation.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` corresponds to `LocalDateTime`, not `Instant`.

Comment: You're wrong see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided

Comment: A PostgreSQL `TIMESTAMP` Java 8 `LocalDateTime` represent a date and time with no time zone information.  By contrast, PostgreSQL `TIMESTAMPTZ` and Java 8 `Instant` represent an absolute point in time whose calendar date and wall clock time depends on the time zone.  These are fundamentally different concepts.  You can convert between them if you know the time zone, which is what Hibernate does, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: Given that an instant is ALWAYS stored in UTC, it make sense to use TIMESTAMP and not TIMESTAMPZ. Because a TIMESTAMPZ will be automatically modified if you change the timezone of your database.

Comment: This isn't quite true. TimestampTZ changes based on the timezone of the client, not the database.